# Dialogflow agent suddenly stopped responding

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

We've been running a dialogflow agent for a number of weeks now, without issue. Today the agent has stopped working.

We're able to launch the agent through both a google home and the actions on google console and trigger our webhook. No errors are reported, but after the first intent the agent "exits":  makes a generic statement (ex. 'How romantic?'), does not trigger the dialog flow webhook, does not proceed to a new intent, and closes.

Has anybody else been seeing this behavior?
Any troubleshooting advice? Nothing obvious is wrong and google won't help.

Comment: check the logs for AoG and dialogflow both.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like you have "How romantic?" as one of your default Replies, and your Fulfillment isn't working for some reason.

You may wish to go to the Settings (by clicking on the gear) and turning on "Log Interactions to Google Cloud" to see what it is trying to send to your webhook, or if it isn't. Make sure you click "Save".

You'll be able to view the logs from the link on that page, or via the Google Cloud Console Stackdriver page for that project. The Actions on Google logs are also available via Stackdriver, and those may help as well.

[image]